# Set hover effect on the img inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML in this fashion

```
<div class="image_area">
   <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>product-detail?product=<?php echo $pl['product_slug'];?>">
     <img src="<?php echo base_url().$pl['product_image'];?>" 
                                style="width:196px;min-height:250px; max-height:250px; border:1px solid #cfcfcf;"/>
   </a>
</div>
```

I want a hover effect on the image such that the border gets highlighted.

I have used this CSS code, but nothing happens

```
.image_area img :hover{ border: 1px solid #b6e2ff}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.image_area img:hover{ border: 1px solid #b6e2ff}
```

No space after img

And to avoid jump of image when hovered, do :

```
.image_area img{ border:1px solid transparent}
```

or you can even better do

```
.image_area a:hover img{ border: 1px solid #b6e2ff}
```

EDIT thanks to nevermind
I didn't see this:

```
style="width:196px;min-height:250px; max-height:250px; border:1px solid #cfcfcf;"/>
```

remove border:1px solid #cfcfcf from there, and put it in 
`.image_area img{ border:1px solid transparent}` 
or `.image_area a img{ border:1px solid transparent}`

Comment: Nothing happened bro.... Nothing is happening.. check this link.. http://the-iguts.com/web/flower1/

Answer (score 0):

No space between img and :hover
You can use

```
.image_area > a img:hover{border:1px solid #b6e2ff;}
```

Answer (score 0):

two notes:
1. do not use style in your html code, add a new class with the following css:

```
width:196px;
min-height:250px; 
max-height:250px; 
border:1px solid #cfcfcf;
```

2. you missed the ";" tag in the end of your line. try use this code:

   ```
   .image_area img:hover { border: 1px solid #b6e2ff; }
   ```